# Getting 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'no such table:' Error when trying to execute SqlStatement

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, sqlite, air

What I am trying to do is open a database in async mode and get some data from my database. To do I wrote this code down below:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("data/mydatabase.db");
            sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();

            sqlConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
            sqlConnection.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);

            sqlConnection.openAsync(file,"read");
```

After, I wrote this code in openHandler method :

```
protected function openHandler(event:SQLEvent):void 
        { 
            Alert.show("Database opened successfully");                 
            startstmt = new SQLStatement();             
            startstmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            startstmt.text = "SELECT tid FROM sectionstable WHERE farma LIKE '%heim%' OR indication LIKE '%heim%' LIMIT 0,10";              
            startstmt.execute();
        }
```

My startstmt is a global SqlStatement variable. When I tested in Sqlite Manager it works fine this query but in adobe-air i am getting this error. Where did i do wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It all looks right. You should check you table name.

Comment: As i told i checked exact same query on Sqlite Manager. Also it works fine when i connect synchronous to database. But i don't want to connect with synchronous mode because of response time and it freezes UI during executing process.